# mongodb installation. service failed to start

Tags: mongodb

Installing MongoDB as a service is failing for me. The install gets to the point where it tries to start the service and then fails:

Service 'MongoDB Server' (MongoDB) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services

This in on a freshly updated new install of Windows 2016

Near default MongoDB 4.2 community install.

Install MongodB as a Service
- Run service as Network Service user.

Directories are not default.

Data Directory : C:\Database\Data

Log Directory : C:\Database\Log

I've granted Network Service full permissions on C:\Database

.net framework 4.6 is installed.

Am I the first person to install MongoDB as a service or something? 
Hard to believe someone didn't catch this before.

Update:
Installing to the default directories works. Brutal QA. Any fix to this?

Comment: MongoDB on windows is supported, but is rare.

Comment: The log files usually reveal the culprit as to why the service failed to start.

Comment: there are no logs because this happens during the install...

why would you comment if you no nothing about the topic? baffling.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case someone else comes across this...

One solution is to just install to the default directories, then after the install is done, stop the service, change the cfg to point to the directories you want and copy the files over. Then start it up.

Comment: When you say "install to the default directories..." do you mean allow default directory configuration for datafiles, or are you referring to the directory where the binaries (mongod.exe) are installed?

Answer (score -1):

Check path of the **MongoDB** service by runninng **Win+R**, type **services.msc** in opened window find **MongoDB server** double click it. Here what I see when installed **MongoDB** to custom folder C:\mongodb [MongoDB server path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvhJr.png)

You probably need to install it into default folder or change path to executable in services.
In latter case run **Win+R** type there **regedit.exe** go to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MongoDB and change **ImagePath** key.

In my case key was `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg" --service`
and I changed it into `"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.cfg" --service`

restart